# How many people of Arya's list are still alive?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

Arya has a list of the people she is going to kill which she starts reciting to herself before bed. Quite a few people from that list are now dead (Especially if you include the Winds of Winter sample chapter from Mercy's POV [currently here](http://www.georgerrmartin.com/excerpt-from-the-winds-of-winter/))

For the people on the list, how many are dead, and how did they die?

Comment: Do you want answers from the books or shows? The answers could vary quite differently now...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At the [wiki entry for Arya](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arya_Stark#Arya_and_Death) the following list is given:

Dead

- King Joffrey. Posioned by Olenna Tyrell.
- Ser Amory. Eaten by Vargo Hoat's bear.
- The Tickler. Arya killed him herself at the Crossroads Inn.
- Polliver. Killed by The Hound at the Crossroads Inn.
- Ser Gregor. Died in extreme pain due to the thickened manticore venom that coated Prince Oberyn's spear.
- Raff the Sweetling. Killed by Arya under her guise of "Mercy" at the Gate, a mummers playhall in Braavos.

Alive

- Ilyn Payne
- Meryn Trant
- Queen Cersei
- Dunsen

Removed

- The Hound

Reanimated:

- Ser Gregor a.k.a The Mountain (He was reanimated by the alchemist)

One might add that "the Hound" is sort of dead, at least according to the story of [the elder brother](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elder_Brother) of Quiet Isle.

Another interesting tidbit is the prophecy given to Cersei by [Maggy the Frog](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maggy_the_Frog), which implies that Cersei will die by the hands of "the valonqar", which is high valyrian for "little brother". Cersei always thought it was Tyrion, but perhaps it could also refer to a certain "little sister"?

Comment: Damn it! Beat me to it!

Comment: I always assumed that the valonqar was not Tyrion, since that's Cersei's immediate interpretation and she never gets ANYTHING right. Given the events of Dance with Dragons I assumed we had finally met the valonqar, but it would be interesting if it really was Arya, perhaps in the guise of a boy...

Comment: Which events are those? Margaery?

Comment: @TLP the appearance of Aegon Targaryan, the "little brother" of Rhaeger's daughter and someone with a pretty strong claim to the throne.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Strangling someone is a highly personal means of murder, and it does not feel correct that Aegon should do that to Cersei. The young queen, however, I always felt was Daenerys.

Comment: I always thought that the Valonqar was Jamie, as her younger brother by a few moments. @MichaelEdenfield

Comment: @Nick Jaime is also an option, and perhaps the most likely one, despite him no longer being able to "wrap his hands" around her throat. It will be interesting to see what UnCat/Brienne does with him.

Comment: Are we 100% sure Ser Gregor is dead?

Comment: @AndresF. According to testimony of the poison, his death was all but certain. Oberyn is some sort of master poisoner. We know Qyburn included Gregor in his necromancy experiments. And of course, it has turned out that dead is not always dead in ASOIAF. But as far as the cruel personality of Gregor, I think we've seen the last of it.

Comment: @TLP True. Ser Robert Strong is probably not much in the personality department.

Comment: "Ser Gregor. Died in extreme pain due to the thickened manticore venom that coated Prince Oberyn's spear." Well, maybe, sorta, technically dead.
Arya leaves the Hound after he dies from an infection.

Comment: @WFred I think you mean "*before* he dies from an infection".

Comment: Wasn't Tywin on the list, at least after Arya realized she should use her 3 kills on him ?

Comment: @DDFirstNameDd No. The list is people who Arya have a personal grudge against.

Comment: There must be a few missing in this answer. Weese was on the list before she got Jaqen to kill him, and Chiswyck probably was too.

Comment: The list should be updated to include Ser Meryn Trant's change in status.

Comment: Meryn Trant is alive in the books, which it seems this question is about.