# Maggy's Prophecy: Do these people need to be dead first?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

According to [Maggy/Maegi the frog's prophecy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maggy):

> Cersei: Will the king and I have children?
>
> Maggy: Oh, aye. Six-and-ten for him, and three for you. Gold shall be their crowns and **gold their shrouds**, she said. And when your tears have drowned you, the valonqar shall wrap his hands about your pale white throat and choke the life from you.

I have always interpreted that as Cersei's three children are destined to die before her.

**Is this correct?**
Or does it mean that when they die (whenever that is), their shrouds will be gold?

Comment: In a recent cameo appearance on "Last Week Tonight", GRRM looked at the camera from his workstation and said "I just killed off three of your favorite characters!", maybe those are Tommen, Myrcella and Ser Pounce. :-P

Comment: Although prophecies don't have to come true. The Stallion Who Mounts the World wasn't even born alive.

Comment: @Nick: Dead things can still mount the world, come winter.

Comment: @Nick what you say is true, but part of the prophecy has already come true. The part about the children born is correct, one of Cersei's is already dead and Tyrion *does* want to kill her.

Comment: Gold shrouds indicate that they die as Baratheons, not Lannisters, i.e. the incest is not revealed.

Comment: @TLP Excellent observation -- Gold shrouds because they are Royalty...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can't know for sure until Martin tells us, but I think yes.

The way I understood the prophecy is this:

> Cersei's children will be dead  way before her (I guess they will die even younger than Joffrey) and she will be really sad and crying
>
> > And when your tears have drowned you [...]
>
> then the valonqar will kill her.

Comment: Seems the reasonable way of interprete it. However... you'll ever now with Martin...

Answer (score 1):

It said in the book that Valonqor means brother, I'm not sure where but I remember it. Because of that prophecy she has always been so wary of Tyrion, because she thinks he's going to kill her and her children, especially after the royal wedding. That's why she didn't want Myrcella to go away. In A Dance of Dragons it goes into the prophecy more, and it all shows to be coming true so far. My theory is that Jaime is going to get so fed up with Cersei that he's going to kill her.

Comment: I got the impression she doesn't want Myrcella to go away because like most mothers she doesn't want her daughter to be taken away to a foreign land and brought up by strangers.

Comment: That probably is the biggest reason, I should have said aside from that, but she does also worry because of the prophecy (presumably).

Comment: Funny thing is, Jaime is her younger brother as well (Born clutching her toes). He may in fact turn out to be the Volnaqar she fears.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@Shevliaskovic's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63106/58193) is correct in terms of the interpretation behind the quote. Per show canon we also have a definitive answer. As per the books well we're still waiting.

**Warning, spoilers for the show beyond this point.**

---

Joffery was killed at the Purple Wedding by poison from Petyr Baelish and Olenna Tyrell. This death has also occured in the books.

Myrcella is then killed by Ellaria Martel with poison after being sent home with Jaime Lannister.

Lastly, Tommen commits suicide after Cersei blows up the Sept of Baelor with Margery Tyrell inside of it.

So as you can see all her children have died and she is still alive at the end of season 7. Therefore, I would say the prophecy is coming true in that they have all died.

Also note as of the end of season 7 it seems that Cersei's almost drowned in her tears after she effectively sends Jaime away.